# What does button type="button" mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

Whilst going through the W3 schools website I was trying to see what it meant when it said `<button type="button"` but I wasn't entirely sure. Could someone please explain to me what this means.

Comment: You should know about Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) Which is a *rich* resource of knowledge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<button>` tag can either be a plain `<button>` (when its type is "button") or a submit button (when its type is "submit", the default).

A "submit" button causes its surrounding `<form>` to be submitted; a plain button doesn't.

Oh, and a `<button>` can also be a "reset" button if you want.

So basically:

- `<button>` is like `<input type="submit">`;
- `<button type="button">` is just a simple button that either triggers an event handler or does nothing;
- `<button type="reset">` is like `<input type="reset">`

(other than the content differences between `<button>` and `<input>` of course)

In some old versions of IE I think the default type was "button", so if you want to make sure things work it's a good idea to specify explicitly the sort of button you want in all cases.

Comment: Also, the input element is a void element. Button is a normal element.

Comment: @Pointy Afair Firefox also defaulted `type="button"`

Comment: @andlrc right; my memory isn't very precise because long ago I got in the habit of being explicit. Once you do that it doesn't matter much :)

Comment: Thanks you @Pointy that's really cleared it up for me :)